# how to put the value from a datatable in double quotes

Tags: c#, string

I have a data table DT with 3 column col1,col2,col3.

I wrote the below code

```
Boolean fst = true;
              string q = Convert.ToString('"');
              foreach (DataColumn co in DT.Columns)
              {   

                    if (fst)
                        {
                          colname = colname + q + co.ColumnName+q  ;
                          fst = false;
                          }
                          else
                          colname = colname +","+ q+co.ColumnName+q ;

               }
```

the output that I want to get is colname= "col1","col2","col3"

but am getting an output  colname="\"col1\",\"col2\",\"col3\"

how can I get the desired output ? any pointers please....

along with this I have a datatable DT with 4 column col1,col2,col3,col4.

str = String.Format("{0,-30}{0,-30}{0,-30}{0,-30}", "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4");

if we write str to a file it will generate the output

```
Heloo                         Heloo                         Heloo                         Heloo
```

I need to do it programatically

```
       string str="";
    Boolean fst = true;
             string q = Convert.ToString('"');
    string frmt="";
              foreach (DataColumn co in DT.Columns)
              {   

                    if (fst)
                        {
                          colname = colname + q + co.ColumnName+q  ;
                          fst = false;
                          }
                          else
                          colname = colname +","+ q+co.ColumnName+q ;

        frmt = frmt +"{0,-30}";

               }

  str= String.Format(frmt, colname);
```

here value of frmt="{0,-30}{0,-30}{0,-30}";
value of colname="Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4";

But if I write str to file it gives bad output. Any pointers on how to achive it ?

Comment: Whereabouts are you getting that output displayed? In the UI, or in Quick Watch when you're debugging?

Comment: I see the wrong string during debugging.

Comment: The debugger escapes the " as it normally is the string termination. So what the debugger shows you is what you want. Check by writing the string to the console.

Comment: it's not the wrong string ... in .NET the `"` char needs to be escaped or the compiler will treat as last char of a string! The same as if you want to assign `"Bruno "maverick" Alexandre"` you need to do: `"Bruno \"maverick\" Alexandre"` or you get a compiler error.

Comment: can anyone please explain how can i get "col1","col2","col3"

Comment: I tried with \" that also didn't work.

Comment: @Flins check my answer that will give answer

Comment: @Flins I suggest reading some of the answers [ok - specifically mine ;)  ]. Your code appears to be fine, I think you're just misinterpreting the debugger.

Comment: @Adrian Wragg   Thanks for the inputs

Comment: @Md. Parvez Alam
Thanks for the inputs

Comment: @Flins , is your problem resolved ?

Comment: @Md. Parvez Alam  Actually I wanted that output string to pass it to another function. please see the editteed question.

Comment: @Md. Parvez Alam   any suggestions please..

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam Stolen? That's quite insulting, actually. My answer was quite clear, and based on my original comment; I have also suggested an improvement that is unrelated to the actual problem, based on the fact that the original questioner has stated elsewhere that they are new to writing code.

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam I literally have no idea what you are referring to (I also don't know what 'updations' means). I answered the question, and then gave additional advice to a newbie.

Comment: That's nice, Keep up such kind of Good work :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is outputting exactly what you want it to output.

You've said in the comments to the question that you're seeing this when you're debugging; this is simply a function of the Watch window, escaping the quote characters for you.

Incidentally, your code could be more efficiently written in a number of ways; one example, that is still reasonable readable:

```
colname = "";
foreach (DataColumn co in DT.Columns) {   
    colname += "\"" + co.ColumnName + "\",";
}
colname = colname.TrimEnd(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape them with a `\`

```
Boolean fst = true;
string q = Convert.ToString('\"');

foreach (DataColumn co in DT.Columns) {   
    if (fst) {
        colname = colname + q + co.ColumnName + q  ;
        fst = false;
    } else
        colname = colname +","+ q + co.ColumnName + q ;
}
```

Also try this

```
colname = colname + @"" + co.ColumnName + @""  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string q = string.empty
              foreach (DataColumn co in DT.Columns)
              {   
    q =+ "\"";
                 q = q + co.ColumnName + "\"" + ",";

               }
q = q.remove(q.length - 1 , 1 )
```

Comment: you can simply remove q = q.remove(q.length - 1 , 1 ) , after loop

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit cleaner:

```
        var tab = new DataTable();

        int row = 0;
        var columnNames = from DataColumn c in tab.Columns
                          let count = row++
                          select string.Format("{0, -30}",c.ColumnName + row);

        string.Join(", ", columnNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is both (a) not generating a correct format string and (b) trying to feed a string to `String.Format` where an array is required.

```
var columns = DT.Columns.Select(c => c.ColumnName);

var colname = string.Join(",", columns.Select(c => string.Format("\"{0}\"", c)));
var str = string.Join("", columns.Select(c => string.Format("{0,-30}", string.Format("\"{0}\"", c))));
```

If you don't need column names to be quoted in `str`, it would be

```
var str = string.Join("", columns.Select(c => string.Format("{0,-30}", c)));
```

Comment: I get an error   Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: I get an error Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: There is something else wrong with your original code, I just noticed it. Fixing the code.